Receiving error when trying to export the list of azure users in Powershell
I'm trying to follow the steps in this article to get the list of users from azure using Powershell but the system is unable to load the module.
What am I doing wrong?
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Install-Module MsIdentityTools -Scope CurrentUser
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Directory.Read.All, AuditLog.Read.All, UserAuthenticationMethod.Read.All
Welcome to Microsoft Graph!

Connected via delegated access using 14d82bbc-204c-4c2f-b7e8-296a70aaba7e
Readme: https://aka.ms/graph/sdk/powershell
SDK Docs: https://aka.ms/graph/sdk/powershell/docs
API Docs: https://aka.ms/graph/docs

NOTE: You can use the -NoWelcome parameter to suppress this message.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Export-MsIdAzureMfaReport -OutputFilePath "C:\Workspace\report.xlsx"
Export-MsIdAzureMfaReport : The 'Export-MsIdAzureMfaReport' command was found in the module 'MSIdentityTools', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module MSIdentityTools'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Export-MsIdAzureMfaReport -OutputFilePath "C:\Workspace\report.xlsx"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Export-MsIdAzureMfaReport:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule


Edited my previous answer since it wasn't completely true (noticed after testing it myself).
I could replicate your error and try the Import-Module MSIdentityTools as stated by the error message you got. This showed this module requires PowerShell 7.0 or greater. I assume you are running the command in Windows PowerShell (most likely 5.1).
Install PowerShell 7.x (also known als PowerShell Core) and your cmdlets should work as intended.
